# Why is the canonical approximate identity positive?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

Let $\{u_n\}$ be an approximative identity for C*-algebra A. Why the element $1-u_n$ is also positive? 
I'm asking about it because in some theorem we use something like this:
$\| a-u_n a \| ^2=\| (1-u_n)^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-u_n)^{\frac{1}{2}}a \| ^2$, but we can do it only if $1-u_n$ is positive.

Thanks for any explanations

Answer (score 3):

In general, $1-u_n$ is not necessarily positive, as you probably have guessed. Consider the $\Bbb C$ $*$-algebra of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the $\sup$-norm, and let $u_n = 1 + \dfrac 1 n$. Then

$$\| u_n f - f \| = \| f + \frac 1 n f - f \| = \frac 1 n \| f \| \to 0$$

which shows that $(u_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is an approximate identity, yet $1 - u_n = - \dfrac 1 n$, clearly not positive.

However, in theorem 3.1.1 from Gerald Murphy's *"$\Bbb C$ $*$-Algebras and Operator Theory"* the net given by $u_\lambda = \lambda \in \Lambda$ is not just an arbitrary approximate identity, but a very special one - so special that it is called "the *canonical* approximate identity" (here $\Lambda$ is the upwards-directed set of the positive elements with norm $< 1$). Remember that in a $\Bbb C$ $*$-algebra, the spectrum $\sigma(x)$ of a self-adjoint element $x$ is contained in $[- \| x \|, \| x \|]$. Since our $u_\lambda$ are taken to be positive, then (by the definition of "positivity") $\sigma (u_\lambda) \subseteq [0, \| u_\lambda \|]$.

Let us show that $1 - u_\lambda \ge 0$; this means that if $\alpha \in \sigma(1 - u_\lambda)$, then we must prove $\alpha \ge 0$. But $\alpha \in \sigma(1 - u_\lambda)$ means that $1 - u_\lambda - \alpha \cdot 1$ is not invertible (by the definition of "spectrum"), which is equivalent to saying that $u_\lambda - (1 - \alpha) \cdot 1$ is not invertible (I have just changed the sign), which implies that $1 - \alpha \in \sigma (u_\lambda) \subseteq [0, \| u_\lambda \|] \subseteq [0,1)$ (because, by choice, $\| u_\lambda \| < 1$), so that $\alpha \in (0, 1]$, which shows that $\sigma(1 - u_\lambda) \subseteq (0, 1]$, which clearly shows that $1 - u_\lambda$ is positive.

Comment: Thank yor for your answer. Could you please explain me the last passage in the theorem 3.1.1 on the page 79 (at the end of the proof). Why we could do like this? https://books.google.ru/books?id=omviBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84&dq=hereditary+algebra+pAp&source=bl&ots=_2Jp4rZdm7&sig=X6ob81dm7zcB3xkOrprYZOGwZO4&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM7O3Tt8fLAhXqCpoKHblyAp4Q6AEILDAD#v=onepage&q=hereditary%20algebra%20pAp&f=false

Comment: @MariaGerasimova: after taking a look at that theorem, I have expanded my answer. The author works with a very special approximate unit, the canonical approximate unit, which has the positivity property that you are asking about.